# Authentication with doorkeeper after facebook authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, doorkeeper

**How to I implement normal doorkeeper oauth2 flow after the user authenticates through facebook  through my mobile app?**

**PS** I am using doorkeeper gem to implement an oauth2 provider for my mobile app. I use resource owner password credentials flow to implement authentication through user's username and password.

So if a user authenticates through facebook through the mobile app first, how do I authenticate a user through doorkeeper with the facebook access token. So no username/password present in this case(which doorkeeper throws out an error of missing params).

What is the correct way to implement this flow.

```
 1. User authenticates from facebook through the mobile app.
 2. Facebook access token is passed to the API server.
 3. If the access token is valid, the api server returns the
    doorkeeper access token.
 4. In case the access token is not valid, the api server returns 401 Unauthorized.
```

**What is the correct approach to implement this flow?** Some guidance in the right direction is very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: well yea.. i implemented the same flow which i mentioned in the question. if the token was invalid, i returned nil and incase the token was valid , i returned user object

Comment: How do you do step 3? Facebook in their response will give me a token... how I check if this token is valid in API server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This extension to the existing doorkeeper grant flows, solves exactly this problem:
https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-grants_assertion

The assertion flow is an exchange between a provider's access_token, for an access token from your oauth provider.

Comment: After implementing this i get `NoMethodError (undefined method 'resource_owner_from_assertion' for #<Doorkeeper::TokensController:0x007fbc0590add0>):` any suggestions?

Comment: I am so sorry for replying so late. Have forgotten about it.Solution looks perfect.I'll accept this answer although I havent tried it myself.I'll have to try it soon.

Answer (score 3):

There is a pull request to fix "NoMethodError (undefined method 'resource_owner_from_assertion' for #)":

Change your Gemfile:

> gem "doorkeeper-grants_assertion", github: "Inittec/doorkeeper-grants_assertion", branch: "master"

Comment: Hi this is not a solution to my problem. Please dont post it as answer. You can however post it as your own question and answer as it will help others too.(Good way to get a few points here. :))